# prerender.io via prerender-node middleware, blacklist hashbang

Tags: regex, prerender, blacklist

I'm successfully using prerender.io service via the prerender.io expresss middleware package prerender-node.

I've not noticed a lot of pollution in my cached results from bots/probes/redirects.

I'm trying to implement a blacklist.

prerender-node state I can do this with something similar to:

```js
if (env === 'production') {
  console.log('production environment, prerender.io enabled')
  const prerender = require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', '******')
  prerender.blacklisted(
    [
      '#!',
      '/#!/',
      '^/#!/.*'
    ]
  )
  app.use(prerender)
}
```

In this example I'm just trying to filter out all hahsbang URLs from being cached.

i.e. `https://example.com/#!/some/url`

But it doesn't seem to be working. After deploying this code, and clearing the cached results. The cache is getting refilled up with results containing '#!'.

Prerender-node README (`https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node`) states this should be simple regex.
And regex pattern validates here: `https://regex101.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting in touch with prerender authors, they've pointed out that 
`#!` is actually being redirected as `?_escaped_fragment_=`

therefore:

```js
const prerender = require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', '******')
prerender.blacklisted('_escaped_fragment_');
app.use(prerender)
```

...seems to be working as desired.